# Почему не запускается React приложение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование

```js
{
  "name": "studi_project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Только начал изучать реакт, сделал как в видео(удалил ненужное), и выдает такую ошибку, что делать?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <div>
      приложение работает!
    </div>
);
```

```css
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не туда смотрите, вы бы показали свой package.json лучше, а не это всё...

Comment: отредактировал.

Comment: Стоп, у вас написано npx start вместо npm start?

Comment: Вы же в курсе что команда npx принимает имя пакета, а пакета start нету?

Answer (score 0):

npm start напиши , то как я понял ты написал npx start